# Reference request: A multidimensional generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, real-analysis

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let $f\colon\R^p\to\R$ be a continuous function. For $u=(u_1,\dots,u_p)$ and $v=(v_1,\dots,v_p)$ in $\R^p$, let
$[u,v]:=\prod_{r=1}^p[u_r,v_r]$;
$u\wedge v:=\big(\min(u_1,v_1),\dots,\min(u_p,v_p)\big)$; $u\vee v:=\big(\max(u_1,v_1),\dots,\max(u_p,v_p)\big)$;
$$\int_u^v dx\, f(x):=
(-1)^{\sum_{r=1}^p\,1(u_r>v_r) }\int_{[u\wedge v,u\vee v]}dx\,f(x).$$
Let $F\colon\R^p\to\R$ be any antiderivative of $f$, in the sense that
$$D_1\cdots D_p F=f,$$
where $D_j$ is the operator of the partial differentiation with respect to the $j$th argument; it is assumed that the result of this repeated partial differentiation does not depend on the order of the arguments with respect to which the partial derivatives are taken. Let $[p]:=\{1,\dots,p\}$. For each set $J\subseteq[p]$, let $|J|$ denote the cardinality of $J$.

Then it is not hard to establish the following multidimensional generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus ([Lemma 5.1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09159)):
\begin{equation}
    \int_u^v dx\, f(x)=\sum_{J\subseteq[p]}(-1)^{p-|J|}F(v_J), 
\end{equation}
where $v_J:=\big(v_1\,1(1\in J)+u_1\,1(1\notin J),\dots,v_p\,1(p\in J)+u_p\,1(p\notin J)\big)$.

Has anyone seen this or similar statement elsewhere? (I am only asking about references, not proofs.)

Comment: Is this not Stokes’ Theorem?

Comment: @RiversMcForge : I don't see a relation with Stokes' theorem.

Comment: It probably generalizes to polytopes (I know this is not what you are asking, but it is just a comment).

Comment: @Malkoun : I think it does; cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09159 -- where the statement  posted here is presented as Lemma 5.1.

Comment: @Iosif Stokes theorem relies the integral of $D_ig$ over, say, the box and the integral of $g$ over it's boundary. This should be Stokes theorem applied $p$ times.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Thank you for your comment. So, it's Green's formula applied $p$ times. Can one get this from a Stokes formula applied just once?

Comment: @IosifPinelis I do not know, but I would not expect this: in Stokes theorem the dimensions in LHS and RHS differ by 1, here they differ by $p$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov : Yes, I guess that is why I did not see a relation with Stokes' theorem; the key was your "applied $p$ times".

Comment: @FedorPetrov : But then, one can also say that it is just the one-dimensional fundamental theorem of calculus applied $p$ times, which is of course true.

Comment: @IosifPinelis well, Stokes theorem for the box (and the derivative in the coordinate direction) is nothing but one-dimensional fundamental theorem of calculus integrated against all other coordinates.

Comment: Taking the limit as $u \to (-\infty, -\infty, -\infty, \ldots, -\infty)$ this also gives you a proof of the $W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n) \hookrightarrow L^\infty$ Sobolev inequality. A variant of it is how I argued Lemmata 3 and 11 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.01460v4.pdf).

Comment: @WillieWong : Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 7):

For an elementary fact like this, which may have been reinvented a thousand times, it is hard to find the first paper where this appeared. However, let me give some missing context. There is a whole industry in **constructive quantum field theory** and **statistical mechanics** about related "smart" interpolation formulas or Taylor formulas with integral remainders. These are used to perform so-called **cluster expansions**.
For the OP's identity, there is no loss of generality in taking $u=(0,0,\ldots,0)$ and $v=(1,1,\ldots,1)$. In this case, via *Möbius inversion in the Boolean lattice*, the formula comes from the following identity.

Let $L$ be a finite set. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^L\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbf{x}=(x_{\ell})_{\ell\in L}\mapsto f(\mathbf{x})$ be a sufficiently smooth function, and let $\mathbf{1}=(1,\ldots,1)\in\mathbb{R}^L$, then
$$
f(\mathbf{1})=\sum_{A\subseteq L}\int_{[0,1]^A}d\mathbf{h}
\left[\left(\prod_{\ell\in A}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\ell}}\right)f\right](\psi_A(\mathbf{h}))
$$
where $\psi_A(\mathbf{h})$ is the element $\mathbf{x}=(x_{\ell})_{\ell\in L}$ of $\mathbb{R}^L$ defined from the element $\mathbf{h}=(h_{\ell})_{\ell\in A}$ in $[0,1]^A$ by the rule:
$x_{\ell}=0$ if $\ell\notin A$ and $x_{\ell}=h_{\ell}$ if $\ell\in A$.
Of course one needs to 1) apply this to all $L$'s which are subsets of $[p]$, 2) use Möbius inversion in the Boolean lattice, and 3) specialize to $L=[p]$, and this gives the OP's identity.

The above formula is the most naive one of its kind used to do a "pair of cubes" cluster expansion. See formula III.1 in the article

A. Abdesselam and V. Rivasseau, ["Trees, forests and jungles: a botanical garden for cluster expansions"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9409094).

It is also explained in words on page 115 of the book

V. Rivasseau, ["From Perturbative to Constructive Renormalization"](http://www.rivasseau.com/resources/book.pdf).

Now the formula is a particular case of a much more powerful one, namely, Lemma 1 in

A. Abdesselam and V. Rivasseau, ["An explicit large versus small field multiscale cluster expansion"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605094),

where one sums over "allowed" sequences $(\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k)$ of arbitrary length of elements of $L$, instead of subsets of $L$. The notion of allowed is based on an arbitrary stopping rule. The above identity corresponds to "allowed"$=$"without repeats", or the stopping rule that one should not tack on an $\ell$ at the end of a sequence where it already appeared. By playing with this kind of choice of stopping rule one can use Lemma 1 of my article with Rivasseau, to prove the Hermite-Genocchi formula, the anisotropic Taylor formula by Hairer in Appendix A of ["A theory of regularity structures"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5113) and many other things. When $f$ is the exponential of a linear form for instance, one can obtain various algebraic identities as in the MO posts

[rational function identity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74102/rational-function-identity/74280#74280)

[Identity involving sum over permutations](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334201/identity-involving-sum-over-permutations/334204#334204)

I forgot to mention, one can use Lemma 1 to derive the Taylor formula from calculus 1. This corresponds to $L$ having one element and defining allowed sequences as the ones of length at most $n$. See

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753212/is-there-any-geometrical-intuition-for-the-factorials-in-taylor-expansions/3753600#3753600

Comment: Thank you for this wealth of information.

Answer (score 5):

The $p=2$ dimensional case is an exercise in Rogawski's calculus textbook. It is exercise 47 on page 885, section 15.1 (Integration in Several Variables) in the 2008 Early Transcendentals edition.

Comment: The $p=2$ case is also stated in the proof of Lemma 6.2 of this 1999 paper of Carbery and Wright: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1683156 , with the three word proof "By Stokes' theorem".

Comment: Correction: that paper is by Carbery, Christ, and Wright.  The general case is implicit in a followup paper https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1928871 of Katz, Krop, and Maggioni in 2002, proved by "a simple application of the fundamental theorem of calculus".

Comment: @ZachTeitler : Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @TerryTao : Thank you for the references.

Comment: The $p = 2$ case is also well-known for people who work in wave equations (for I hope obvious reasons). For example, it is used lots when studying the spherically symmetric Einstein-scalar-field model in mathematical relativity; I'd say every other paper there uses this formula either explicitly or implicitly.